# How can I change the certificates on the nodes bootstrapped with chef

Tags: chef-infra

We have about 100 nodes that are bootstrapped to the on prem chef server using certs. Now we need to change the certs on the server. I have figured out that part but if I do that all those nodes will not be able to check back to the server. How can I change the certs so that I dont lose the connectivity to the nodes and dont have to go around individually changing the certs on each node. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple public keys attached to a single API client, which allows for safe key rotation. However we have no tooling for this that I know of, so you'll have to write that yourself.